How to Upload images using Apollo GraphQL v4
I have been working with Apollo GraphQL v4 for a blog template and here I need to upload images from a GraphQL Mutation. But I am getting the following error
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "This operation has been blocked as a potential Cross-Site Request Forgery (CSRF). Please either specify a 'content-type' header (with a type that is not one of application/x-www-form-urlencoded, multipart/form-data, text/plain) or provide a non-empty value for one of the following headers: x-apollo-operation-name, apollo-require-preflight\n",
      "extensions": {
        "code": "BAD_REQUEST",
        "stacktrace": [
          "BadRequestError: This operation has been blocked as a potential Cross-Site Request Forgery (CSRF). Please either specify a 'content-type' header (with a type that is not one of application/x-www-form-urlencoded, multipart/form-data, text/plain) or provide a non-empty value for one of the following headers: x-apollo-operation-name, apollo-require-preflight",
          "",
          "    at new GraphQLErrorWithCode (/Users/bhavikji/Work/apollo_graphql_boilerplate_test/node_modules/@apollo/server/src/internalErrorClasses.ts:15:5)",
          "    at new BadRequestError (/Users/bhavikji/Work/apollo_graphql_boilerplate_test/node_modules/@apollo/server/src/internalErrorClasses.ts:116:5)",
          "    at preventCsrf (/Users/bhavikji/Work/apollo_graphql_boilerplate_test/node_modules/@apollo/server/src/preventCsrf.ts:91:9)",
          "    at ApolloServer.executeHTTPGraphQLRequest (/Users/bhavikji/Work/apollo_graphql_boilerplate_test/node_modules/@apollo/server/src/ApolloServer.ts:1048:20)",
          "    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)"
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}

index.ts
import express, { json } from "express";
import cors from "cors";
import { buildSubgraphSchema } from "@apollo/subgraph";
import { expressMiddleware } from "@apollo/server/express4";
import { ApolloServer } from "@apollo/server";
import { typeDefs } from "./schema";
import { resolvers } from "./resolvers";
import { connect } from "mongoose";
import {
  createApollo4QueryValidationPlugin,
  constraintDirectiveTypeDefsGql,
} from "graphql-constraint-directive/apollo4";
import getTokenForRequest from "./middleware/auth";
// @ts-ignore
import graphqlUploadExpress from 'graphql-upload/graphqlUploadExpress.js';

async function startApolloServer() {
  const PORT = process.env.PORT || 4000;
  const app = express();

  app.use(cors());
  app.use(express.json());
  const schema = buildSubgraphSchema({
    typeDefs: [constraintDirectiveTypeDefsGql, typeDefs],
    resolvers,
  });
  const plugins = [createApollo4QueryValidationPlugin({})];
  const server = new ApolloServer({
    schema, 
    // Using graphql-upload without CSRF prevention is very insecure.
    csrfPrevention: true,
    plugins,
  });
  // Note you must call `start()` on the `ApolloServer`
  // instance before passing the instance to `expressMiddleware`
  await server.start();
  app.use(
    "/graphql",
    cors(),
    json(),
    graphqlUploadExpress(),
    expressMiddleware(server, {
      context: async ({ req, res }) => ({
        // get the user token from the headers
        token: await getTokenForRequest(req),
      }),
    })
  );
  // connect to mongoose
  try {
    await connect(
      "mongodb.url"
    );
    // start the Express server
    app.listen(PORT, () => {
      console.log(`
      Server is running!
      Query at http://localhost:${PORT}/graphql
  `);
    });
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}

startApolloServer();

resolvers.ts
uploadBlogPhotos: async(_,{ image }, contextValue) => {
  if (!contextValue.token) {
    throwUnauthorizedError();
  }
  return uploadBlogPhotos(image, contextValue)
}

schema.ts
type BlogPhotos {
    id: ID
    url: String!
    filename: String!
    mimetype: String!
    encoding: String!
    createdAt: String
    updatedAt: String
  }

RecordController.ts
export const uploadBlogPhotos = async (image, contextValue) => {
  const userID = contextValue.token.userID;
  const user = await User.findOne({ _id: userID });
  if (!user) {
    throwUnauthorizedError();
  }
  const { filename, mimetype, encoding, createReadStream } = await image;
      console.log(`Uploading ${filename}...`);
      const stream = createReadStream();
      const pathName = path.join(__dirname, `/src/image/${filename}`);
      // This is purely for demonstration purposes and will overwrite the
      // local-file-output.txt in the current working directory on EACH upload.
      const out = fs.createWriteStream(pathName);
      stream.pipe(out);
      await finished(out);
      const blogphotos = new BlogPhotos({
        url: pathName,
        filename,
        mimetype,
        encoding
      });
      const uploadedPhoto = await blogphotos.save();
  return {
    ...uploadedPhoto._doc,
    id: uploadedPhoto._id.toString(),
    createdAt: uploadedPhoto.createdAt.toISOString(),
    updatedAt: uploadedPhoto.updatedAt.toISOString(),
  };
}

It's a learning project, and I am not sure what I have missed. I will appreciate if someone help me in this.
TIA

When making that request on the client, you have to set one of the headers x-apollo-operation-name, apollo-require-preflight as the error message indicates. Only that way can the server disinguish intended uploads from CSRF attacks.
